# Reading JSON data in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I am trying to import JSON data from IEXAPI into Google Sheets, and have found the following function [here](https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/):

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

The JSON that I'm trying to read is:

```
    [{
    "symbol":"AAPL",
    "sector":"electronictechnology",
    "securityType":"cs",
    "bidPrice":0,
    "bidSize":0,
    "askPrice":0,
    "askSize":0,
    "lastUpdated":1587067200000,
    "lastSalePrice":286.48,
    "lastSaleSize":100,
    "lastSaleTime":1587067199848,
    "volume":357754
}]
```

But when I call the function in Google Sheets I get the error `Node Not Available`:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/tops?token=MY_API_KEY&symbols=aapl", "symbol")
```

I don't understand what is wrong, because `symbol` is a rootnode in the JSON. Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is wrapped in an array.

```js
json = json[0][patharray[i]];
```